# Missing template arguments and class implementation errors

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to C++ and SO to I apologize in advance if everything isn't up to snuff.

Below are the first few lines of my main function. I get an error on the 6th line: 'missing template arguments before c1'. As you can see further below the class 'complex' has to double data members which should both be initialized to 0 with the default constructor. entering complex fixed this error but I don't believe I should need a template in the first place. Another issue is that after I make this change, the compiler does not recognize the first member function that I use `c1.get_real()` which I suspect is due to the addition of the template argument.

```
#include <fstream> // For ofstream class declaration
#include <iostream> // For cout, endl
#include <Complex> // So we can access the complex class declaration (hint: see Complex.cpp)
#include <string>


int main()
{
    string filename; filename = "complex-test.txt";
    ofstream fout(filename.c_str());
    fout<<"Defining complex object c1 and calling default ctor"<<endl;
    complex c1;
    fout<<"Testing accessors and that default ctor initialized c1 to 0 + 0i"<<endl;
    fout<<"c1.get_real() returned "<<c1.get_real()<<endl;
```

My Complex.cpp file which implements my class member functions:

```
#include <iomanip>      // For fixed, setprecision()
#include <sstream>      // For stringstream class
#include "Complex.hpp"  // For the complex class declaration

using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// + complex() :
// PSEUDOCODE
// Call init() passing 0 and 0 as the arguments.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    complex::complex()
    {
        init(0,0);
    }


 complex::complex(double init_real, double init_imag)
 {
    init(init_real, init_imag);
 }


 double complex::get_imag()
 {
     return m_imag;
 }


double complex::get_real()
{
    return m_real;
}


void complex::init(double init_real, double init_imag)
{
    m_real = init_real;
    m_imag = init_imag;
}


void complex::set_imag(double s)
{
    m_imag = s;
}


void complex::set_real(double s)
{
    m_real = s;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// + to_string() : string
//
// DESCRIPTION
// Returns a string representation of the complex object. For example, if m_real is -2.3333333
// and m_imag is -21.456789123, this function will return the string "(-2.3333 - 21.4568i)".
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string complex::to_string()
{
    stringstream sout;
    sout << fixed << setprecision(4);
    sout << "(" << get_real();
    double imag = get_imag();
    if (imag < 0) {
        sout << " - " << -imag << 'i';
    } else if (imag > 0) {
        sout << " + " << imag << 'i';
    }
    sout << ")";
    return sout.str();
}
```

Here is the header file for the class:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_HPP  // See the comments in the header comment block regarding these two lines.
#define COMPLEX_HPP

#include <string> // Included because we are using the string class in to_string()
using namespace std;

class complex
// Write the public section of the class declaration.
{
    public:

    complex();

    complex(double , double);

    double get_imag();

    double get_real();

    void set_imag(double);

    void set_real(double);

    string to_string();
    private:

    void init(double, double);

    double m_real;

    double m_imag;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This is what you get when you use `using namespace std;`. There exists a standard class [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), and since you added all names from `namespace std` to global namespace, the compiler is confused on which one should it choose.

Comment: Also see [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen OP (hopefully) doesn't include `<complex>` though

Comment: @Swordfish I guess one of the system headers includes it? I don't see any other explanation, since OP's code has no templates in it.

Comment: `using namespace std;` -- First and foremost, remove this from the `Complex.hpp` header file.

Comment: If what you have in your files is what you have shown here could you clean your project and recompile it? I don't see a declerations of a template in your code to begin with so..??

Comment: The only thing from namespace `std` used in your `complex.hpp` is `std::string`, and is easily fully namespace qualified with a few more keystrokes (less than it took to type out `using namespace std;`. Unrelated, *all* of those getters should be `const`.

Comment: @Elmer it's not `string` but `std::string`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen all that's implimentation defined so they are free to include the entire STL with just <string> if they want to, in practice though it's possible that iomanip or the stream classes use <complex>, just my best guess

Comment: @Elmer The full name of the class is `std::string`. If you add `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code, compiler will let you omit the `std::` qualifier. Now, when you have removed it, the names have to be fully qualified, using `std::` prefix for every standard class/object/function. This may seem tedious, but is actually a very good practice and makes code more readable for others (and lets you avoid some weird bugs like the one you encountered).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That resolved that issue, but now I'm getting a new error message saying 'complex is not declared in this scope' I added the header files I used for my main file? Did I not reference the .cpp file for my class correctly (it's named Complex.cpp and is in the same folder as the rest of the files)

Comment: Did you `#include "Complex.hpp"` in your main?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, but I did include it in my "Complex.cpp" file which I did include in the main file? Does this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

If you're running your compiler on a case-insensitive operating system (Windows ?), this line:

```
#include <Complex> // So we can access the complex class declaration (hint: see  Complex.cpp)
```

will cause the standard header `<complex>` (all lowercase) to be included and therefore the template [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) to be load.  Note that on a linux system, you would get the right error (that the header Complex with upaercase) is not found.

You then have two complex types in your code: `std::complex` and you `complex`.  The fact that you have `using namespace std` makes `complex` and `std::complex` synonyms.  This is where your error comes from.

### The solution

First, if you don't need the standard complex, don't include it.  So in the main unit, use the same include than in your `complex.cpp`:

```
#include "Complex.hpp"  // For YOUR complex class declaration
```

Second, avoid `using namespace std`.  [At least in your headers](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-using-directive).  Just prefix standard objects with `std::`.  Or list the standard objects that you explicitly want to use without the prefix:  `using std::cout;`.

*Additional remark: some [C++ styles](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Type_Names) suggest to define your own class names with a starting capital.  This prevents conflicts with the std.  But this approach is not a remplacement for the recommendations above, since name clashes would sill be possible with other libraries that may use the same kind of style.*